# Electric Field and Electrostatics

Tags: electricity

Is **centre of charge** possible in Electrostatics? or is it just a method to reduce calculation Complications(under specified terms and conditions)?

Comment: What does "centre of charge" mean?  Can you be more descriptive?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible of centre of charge. We do it because of avoiding complication.

Comment: The second sentence seems to indicate that we *can* do it, which contradicts the first sentence...